# how to update 2 objects in useState based on one input

Tags: reactjs

for example:

```
const people = [{name: "alpha", gender: "male"}, {name: "beta", gender: "female"}]
const [data, setData] = useState([])
const handleChange = (event) => {
setInputs({...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
}
```

html:

```
<input name = "people" type="text" list="peoples" value={data.people} onChange={handleChange}> 
</input>
<datalist id="noSuratJalan1" name="noSuratJalan1">
                            {people.map((item, index) => 
                                <option key={index} value={item.name}>age: {item.age}</option>
                            )}
                        </datalist>
<input name = "gender" type="text" list="peoples" value={data.gender} onChange={handleChange}></input>
```

how to autmatically update the gender based on the selected name from the input datalist?
so like when i choose alpha, the input gender should automatically be "male"

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track on selected value:

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(null)

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setSelectedValue( {[event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  setInputs({...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value});

}
```